# I would like to do Validation on Lead fields before the 'Convert' button is clicked

Tags: lead-conversion, convert

So,
we have several lead fields, that are only needed upon conversion. There are fields mappings for these fields, which populate correctly on the account/oppty new/converted records.
However, they are not mandatory on the lead object.

My thought was to do a validation check on the lead fields before the user clicks on the convert button.

I do not want to create a custom convert button.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using the solution suggested here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/336827/260

So, I created a boolean formula field, which includes all the validations that the conversion needs.

I hide the 'Convert' button, as long as this field is false.

Answer (score 3):

You can use first enable [Require validation for Converted Leads](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000331020&type=1) setting under lead setting.

Then you can use [IsConverted](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm) field on lead to check required fields on leads.

A sample example would be:-

```
AND(
IsConverted = TRUE,
OR(
   ISBLANK( your_required_field1__c ),
   ISBLANK( your_required_field2__c )
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't fit our users' needs, as they don't want to go to the convert button, and than get an error from the 'Convert' action.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcomplicate, just set this in Lead Settings.
Make sure the fields are mandatory
[image]